Load input choices from a secret in JSON format
I have stored a JSON array in secrets.ENVIRONMENT_OPTIONS on GitHub and am trying to load the input choices from this secret. However, it's not working, and the network tab shows a 500 error. How to resolve this issue?
The JSON is:
["dev","staging","uat"]

Here's my workflow file:
name: Release Branch Android Build

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'Select the environment'
        required: true
        type: choice
        options: ${{ secrets.ENVIRONMENT_OPTIONS }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

I have also tried ${{ fromJson(secrets.ENVIRONMENT_OPTIONS) }}, but no success.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/accessing-contextual-information-about-workflow-runs#context-availability

You may need to store this in vars.
